# One-column Minted in two-column paper (new ACM Template)

Tags: two-column, verbatim, minted, acm, acmart

The Association for Computing Machinery is currently transitioning to a [unified LaTeX Class](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) for all of their conference proceedings after August of 2017.

I've got several Minted blocks of code, which are too long to fit in a column of a two-column article. For figures and such, I can just use `\begin{figure*}`, but as far as I know, there's no equivalent for Minted (or Verbatim, which I think it is based off of).

I doubt I will be the only one trying to squeeze code snippets into an ACM paper.

Is there any way to do this, or a recommended way to get Minted to play nice with 2-column papers?

Comment: Please have a look to the topic minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). It would be great to see minimal working examples in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i'm not an expert but I found out two ways to extend the minted code in one column.

First one: **One Column**

The \onecolumn permit to extend all in one column.

```
\onecolumn
\begin{minted}
# some 1-column code here!
\end{minted}
```

Second one: **Float with listing environment**

```
\begin{listing*}
\begin{minted}
# other 1-column code!
\end{minted}
\end{listing*}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Some compilable code that illustrates your solution would be nice.